# How to used kubernetes apiserver get CNI types?

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have more kubernetes cluster and use different CNI plugin. 
When I coding a CMDB agent ,I want used kubernetes apiserver get CNI plugin, next write in to my CMDB database.

I used Go languages.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a thing. You would have to write a separate detection mode for each CNI plugin. Additionally it's probably possible (if inadvisable) to have multiple plugins active on the same node as long as only one tries to configure each pod.